# Standardness of ordinals $\neq \omega$

Tags: set-theory

For the first infinite von Neumann ordinal $\omega$, I think I understand (per threads [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4661395) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4667248)) the distinction between "standard" and "non-standard" $\omega$. But I'm wondering how the notion of "standardness" (or non-standardness) can be extended to larger ordinals.

- Is there a notion of "standardness" that can meaningfully be defined for larger ordinals (like $\omega_{1}$ for example)?
- If a set universe has non-standard $\omega$ does that necessarily imply non-standardness of larger ordinals?
- Is it possible for $\omega$ to be standard but some larger ordinal to be non-standard?

My semi-educated guess would be that "standardness" of all von Neumann ordinals flows from the standardness of $\omega$ (if $\omega$ is standard, then it's essentially true by definition that the other ordinals are also standard). But I'm not at all certain of this...

Comment: The notion you're looking for is well-foundedness. Because of the rank function, any non-wellfoundedness (i.e. any infinite decreasing membership chain) leads to an infinite decreasing sequence of ordinals. It is possible for an $\omega$-model to not be well-founded... the funny business just starts higher up rather than right after the standard naturals.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: In an $\omega$-model of ZF, I would think that the Axiom of Foundation should rule out such non-wellfoundedness, should it not?

Comment: No. Why should foundation rule it out for $\omega$-models when it doesn't for non-$\omega$-models?

Comment: [For reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2122125/not-well-founded-omega-models-of-zfc)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen : Are you saying that in a non-well-founded $\omega$-model of ZF, there can exist an infinite membership chain? That would seem inconsistent with the Axiom of Foundation. For example in Jech’s *Set Theory* (1st ed., free at archive.org books), sub-chapter 9 starts by stating the Axiom of Regularity (a.k.a. Axiom of Foundation), then says “as a consequence, there is no infinite sequence $x_0 \ni x_1 \ni x_2 \ni \ldots$”

Comment: Or am I getting confused somehow between the $\textbf{E}$ relation of the model and the “true” $\in$ of the universe?

Comment: @NikS In any non-well-founded model $M$ of ZFC, there exists (from our external point of view), an infinite descending membership chain. That chain is given by a function from our external $\omega$ to $M$. An infinite descending membership chain internal to $M$ would be an element of $M$ which is a function with domain $\omega^M$. Now there is no reason why the existence of the former should imply the existence of the latter, even if our $\omega$ is isomorphic to $\omega^M$.

Comment: @NikS What Alex said. But the point I'm trying to emphasize is that non-$\omega$-models are ill-founded, so this is nothing new. If the model's natural numbers are not (externally) well-ordered, then there is (externally) an infinite descending membership chain. The new thing here is that $Ord^M$ can fail to be (externally) well-ordered, even if its initial segment $\omega^M$ is.

Comment: @NikS Oh, I think maybe I see the point of confusion. By infinite descending membership chain we mean a sequence $x_n$ of elements of $M$ such that $x_{n+1}Ex_n$ for all $n$. Now, if $M$ is an $\omega$-model, then we could also view this as a map from $\omega^M\to M$ satisfying this property. But there's no guarantee that this mapping corresponds to a set in $M$... a model will generally be missing some of these functions (remember, countable models exist and in that case they clearly have to be missing some). So $M$ can still satisfy foundation.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen : Ah, OK. So, to summarize: If we define ***”actually” finite*** according to the normal notion of counting with the  (standard) natural numbers, then 1) In a well-founded model of ZF, every descending membership chain is “actually” finite 2) A non-well-founded model $M$ of ZF (whether $\omega$-model or not) contains descending membership chains which are “actually” infinite but the model doesn’t “think” of such a chain as an “infinite sequence” because $M$ lacks any function which implements a bijective mapping between $\omega^M$ and the sets in the chain…(cont’d)

Comment: …3) An ordinal $\alpha$ is “standard” iff: for every descending membership chain comprised of members of $\alpha$, the chain is “actually” finite. Have I got these points 1-3 about right?

Comment: @NikS Mostly. It's not really that the model doesn't think of the chain as an infinite sequence so much as it doesn't know about the chain at all.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen - To clarify: you mean that the model “knows about” the chain iff it contains a function that implements a bijective mapping between $\omega^M$ and the sets in the chain? (i.e. the chain *exists* in the model even if the model doesn’t “know” about it in the aforementioned sense of “knowing”)

Comment: @NikS A chain is a sequence... it is a function between $\omega$ and $M.$ Yes, by "knows about" I mean this function is "implemented" inside $M.$ In very precise terms, if $f:\omega\to M$ is the chain in question, then is there a $f^M\in M$ whose $E$-elements are exactly $\{(n^M, f(n))^M:n\in \omega\},$ where $(,)^M$ means $M$'s ordered pairing function and $n^M$ is $M$'s interpretation of the natural number $n$.